# Solr Query Parameter LIKE

Tags: web, search, solr, opencms

I want to search through my content using Solr. My question is, is there a possibility to search for a text, which contains a certain character sequence?

Example: I have a text like "This is my Regitrationmail"
I want a query for the search of "registration" or "mail" or even "Registrationm" etc. etc.
Also the query should match if the content or the title match the query.

this is my current query:

```
q=text:registration~20
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it can be handled at the time of tokenization...you can use the ngram tokenizer at the the time of indexing...https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html

Comment: As long as you're matching against the tokens themselves you can use the regex support: `q=text:/registration/` - however, it might not be as performant as necessary - that depends on you use case. The ngram solution trades the number of tokens for performance, so you get better performance but a larger index.